# Postman Oauth 2 callback url - Chrome App

Tags: google-chrome, oauth-2.0, postman

I am using The Chrome App for Postman and I am setting up my Access Tokens using OAUTH2. When I fill out the form, I am using the following:

Auth Url: https://[MY_API_URL]/api/authorize

Access Token URL: https://[MY_API_URL]/api/request/token

Client ID: xxxxxxxxxxx

Client Secret: xxxxxxxxxx

Scope: blank

Grant Type: Authorization Code

The callback url in my outh server is set to "https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback"

When I click Request Token, I am taken to the proper Authentication page. When I submit my credentials, a new Chrome tab opens up with a blank page with the url https://app.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback?code=xxxxxxxxxx

I expect that this is supposed to redirect to the app so it can perform the access token request. from the access token url, but nothing is happening. Is this not the right callback uri?

Answer (score 8):

This is an old question and things have changed since.

Google deprecated [Chrome Apps](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/overview/), so Postman had to deprecate their old Chrome App client too, and so the old redirection URL (`https://www.postman.com/oauth2/callback`) no longer works.

According to [this](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/9390), with the more recent versions of Postman, the new redirection URL is `https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback`.

Answer (score 3):

You have change your permission type. Use `Client Credentials` instead of `Authorization`

Comment: Can I change my call back url? It's by defailt coming as  - "https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback"

Answer (score 2):

I also faced same problem.
Just change `Grant Type: Authorization Code` to `Grant Type: Client Credentials`.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly as mentioned in other comments, for `client_credentials` it would work but for the `Implicit` or `Authorization Code`, I used "https://app.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback" as the callback url and it worked. Also it need to be configured in the application settings in oauth provider.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this callback url:

```
https://getpostman.com/oauth2/callbackurl
```